# AWS SDK How to increase ECS cluster ec2 instance without auto scaling

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I'm using Demon service in ECS Cluster. Demon service cannot use auto-scaling.

I want to increase cluster ec2 instance count via aws ecs sdk.

But I can't find the function doing this.

Is there someone who knows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in aws cli sdk. by changing AsgMaxSize

```golang
    import "github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/ecs-cli/modules/clients/aws/cloudformation"
    ...

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("AKID", "Secret", ""),
    })

    cloudClient := cloudformation.NewCloudformationClient(&config.CommandConfig{
        Session:sess,
    })

    stackName := "EC2ContainerService-name"
    params, err := cloudClient.GetStackParameters(stackName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    log.Println(params)
    newParams, err := cloudformation.NewCfnStackParamsForUpdate([]string{"AsgMaxSize"}, params)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    newParams.Add("AsgMaxSize", "3")

    out, err := cloudClient.UpdateStack(stackName, newParams)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
```